# Jinja2 messes up less than and greater than chars

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

So in Jinja2 I have this code:

```
<div id='posts'>
    <!-- Display all posts -->
    {% for p in posts %}
        <div class='post'>
            <h3>{{ p[1] }}</h3>
            {{ p[2] }}  
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

The `p[2]` is what's important here. It's just a unicode string with the value of `"<p>content</p> <b>bold</b>"`. I want it to display as html, but when I load the page, this is how it's displayed:

[image: It it displaying improperly]

However, when I view the page source, it looks like this:

```
&lt;p&gt;content&lt;/p&gt; &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
```

All I want is for it to display as normal HTML. I have a feeling this is some weird encoding issue, and I know little about that. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [autoescaping](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#autoescaping). It protects you against things like XSS injection.

If you're sure your content is safe, you can turn it off with

```
{% autoescape false %}...{% endautoescape %}
```